# How can Stella be Christian while her father is from Jewish religion?

Tags: short-stories

In the story "The Magic Barrel", does the narrator give any clues that the father (Pinny) and daughter (Stella) are from different religions: Jewish and Christian respectively ?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/how-can-stella-salzman-be-christian-while-her-father-pinny-salzman-is-jewish) the same question on two different sites. Please pick one site to post your question on, not on both at the same time.

Comment: I had to post twice as I didn't exactly know which site would be appropriate and ended up here in this site. Sorry !

Comment: Aside from the (allegedly) magical barrel, is there anything about this story that's sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: It's Jewish fantasy

Comment: You are asking two questions in one post. Please try to ask one at a time. Separate them into two posts if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for informing

Comment: @Yubraj - It's certainly *allegorical fiction* but that doesn't make it fantasy

Comment: Where should I ask this question then?

Comment: Literature Stack Exchange or Judaism Stack Exchange.  And you already have it on Literature so I'm sure you will get an answer.

Comment: How surprising !I have asked this question related to Literature; from short story "Magic Barrel". It's story related to Literature, isn't it?

Comment: Only 19 people have seen your question on Literature.SE and it's been there less than a day. Just be patient. Offer a bounty if you can. Cross-posting the same question to multiple sites is, as Mithrandir has already explained, frowned upon, especially if said question is off-topic on one or more of those sites, as it is here.

Comment: To be clear, my understanding is that religious stories are de-facto off-topic here because calling them "science *fiction* or *fantasy*" may imply that they never happened, and we don't want to open that particular can of worms.

Comment: @F1Krazy - This isn't a religious text, and it isn't even fantasy. It's entirely mundane, although possibly allegorical.

Comment: I never read the text you are mentioning, and now I am curious: what is your logical reason for stating that a son can't give a duck of his/her parent religion, to the point tha you need to ask explanations about it online? The world is plenty of kids of Christians who decide to be atheists, and the opposite applies too. Why this specific character should be forbidden to take a choice?

Answer (score 4):

Unrelated to SF&F, but in Judaism, you are considered Jewish only if your mother is Jewish, unrelated to your father's religion.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew%3F):

> Orthodox Judaism and Conservative Judaism follow Jewish law (Halakha),
>   deeming a person to be Jewish if their mother is Jewish or they
>   underwent a halakhic conversion.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/13438

Comment: @Alex I can't believe that question was worth 100 reputation bounty! I should be more active on that forum I guess!

Comment: Indeed, we could always use some new blood there.

Comment: So, Was she really from christian? It's not mentioned in the story "sonny's blues"

Comment: My question wasn't fully addressed while writing the answer!

Comment: You asked two questions, I answered the one I know. If her mother is Christian and her father is Jewish, she is considered Christian.

Comment: Ok, Is there any proof or clue in the story that her mother is really a Christian?

Comment: Having now read the story, there is nothing to indicate that either the girl or her mother weren’t Jewish.